# How to formalize my argument for existence of $\lim \limits_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \int_{\epsilon}^{c} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

I know this exists - $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not defined on $0$ but it has an asymptote there. However, I'm finding it difficult to formalize my argument in a way that I don't say things which might not be always true.
I was trying to do it defining a function $f$ by:
$f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ if $x > 0$, $  f(0) = 1$.
Then $f$ is continuous in $[0, +\infty[$, because $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = 1$$ and so is integrable in an interval $[0,c] \subset [0, +\infty[$.
I don't know if this suffices to say that the original integral exists, because $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not defined in $0$.

Comment: I have written an answer. Had not noticed your title. The problem of whether the integral of the title exists,  and the problem of whether the integral of your $f$ exists are closely related, but different. What you wrote is certainly enough to show that the integral $\int_0^c f(x)\,dx$ exists. But I suspect that the integral of the title was defined in your course as in my answer.

Comment: Andre, yes, that's right, It's a limit...

Comment: That's good, since that's what my answer assumed!

Answer (score 1):

As $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ we find that the singularity at $x=0$ is removable. As the only discontinuities of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ on $\left[0,c\right]$ are removable for all $c\geq 0$ we find that the integral exists.

Answer (score 1):

Your title contains the expression
$$\int_{0^+}^c \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx.$$
I expect this has been defined (for $c\gt 0$) as being equal to the following limit, if it exists:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^c\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx.\tag{1}$$
So does the limit exist? As $\epsilon$ approaches $0$ through positive values, the integral $\int_{\epsilon}^c\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$, as soon as $\epsilon$ reaches a reasonably small value, like $\min(c,1)$, is increasing. It is clearly bounded above, since $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ has absolute value $\lt 1$. So the limit (1) exists.

Comment: I think your approach was very nice